# Best way to develop a html/jquery seating application (or should we use silverlight/flash)

Tags: c#, jquery, silverlight, flash, model-view-controller

We want to create a multipurpose seating web.

The administrative portion is where our super users can either define a location as a numbers of rows, with a number of seats in each ( ie a cinema/concert lokale). The other option they have should be a much more flexible "seating" arrangement. Here we want the superuser to be able to upload an image and then draw places (ie a camping place).

The user portion is either a simple page with all the rows of seats drawn or a view of the image with the drawn places overlaid. The user should then be able to choose a number of "tickets" and select places. For the fixed map, we want the tickets to be sticky (ie if you choose 3, they should be seated besides each other if possible).

My question is what is the best technology to create something like this in? We were hoping mvc + jquery could be a good solution, but we are also looking on silverlight (or flash).

If we where to use html/jquery, how would you implement it?

Comment: Perhaps you can get some ideas from this example: [http://www.digital-web.com/extras/jquery_crash_course/](http://www.digital-web.com/extras/jquery_crash_course/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is the way to go. So your fronted stack would be

- HTML/CSS
- javascript
- SVG (VML)

Try this: http://raphaeljs.com/

Don't use Silverlight or Flash. There's no need, they'll exclude iOS and perform poorly on mobile browsers that do support them.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if there is already and SDK / Library available (e.g. http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html).

In Silverlight you have several choices that cold save you tons of work (SyncFusion ,yWorks), we have develop and SDK that is being use by some third parties (e.g. seats reservation on a football stadium), if you want to check a demo: http://silverdiagram.net/Scripts/SD.Editor.html

Cheers
  Braulio

Comment: Looks pretty good...and pretty expensive. But we will look into it after the cheaper solutions.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend dojo if you want to create easy gui for mobile and desktops

http://dojotoolkit.org/widgets

http://dojotoolkit.org/grids-charts

Comment: Jquery/dojo/whatever JS library, I prefer Jquery mainly because I've gotten used to it. The question is HOW would you go around developing something like this.

Comment: ok i prefer jq too but to to something like this you have to configure multiple jq plugins it will be painfull but it can be done